# Counting contractions as 2 words instead of 1 in str_word_count()

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the word counts of a string, but I want to count contractions as 2 words instead of 1. Is there a way to do this with str_word_count()?

```
$string = "i'm not";
$count = str_word_count($string);

echo $count;
```

**Result:**

2

**Want Result:**

3

Comment: You could instead use `sizeof(explode(" ",$string))` to count the words delimited by spaces. Then you could do something like `sizeof(explode("'",$string2))` to count how many of those words are contractions. Obviously the trouble with this method is sentences like `I'm going to my friend's house` would count to 8 instead of 7 like I imagine you'd like since `friend's` would be counted as two words even though it's meant to be possesive.

Comment: @hobenkr Yeah wouldn't want (friend's) to count as 2 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_English_contractions), there are many contractions in the English language (some I've never seen before - some are not used anymore). So the following suggestion is **not exhaustive, by far**.

You can decide to ignore most, and concentrate on `n't`, `'d`, `'re`, `'s`, `'ll` - feel free to add more.
Then, count the words in the string (using `str_word_count`) and search for the above sub-strings, adding 1 for each found.

Comment: Yes. This is the most effective way.

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines too, but in my head, I was adding in pronouns to the match too. Forgot we could just match for the contractions themselves, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass by this way:

```
$string = "i'm not";
$replacements = array('"', "'");
$count = str_word_count(str_replace($replacements, " ", $string));

echo $count; // output 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately the count of `Joe's house` would be 3 instead of 2 even though it is not the equivalent of `Joe is house`.

Comment: What if the string contains `'` in other places? Like "I'm not 'bored'" - your method would yield 6 instead of 4.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy True that.

Comment: @frosty In this case... you need to add a dictionary with all of equivalences on the english vocabulary, like "i'm" equals "i am", etc, then you replace every "i'm" by "i am" and you can count. This is not possible otherwise.

Comment: @hobenkr Of course we could try to match every single pronouns that comes with a contraction, but that would be a pain, lol.

Comment: I think @keupsonite is right that without going the dictionary method, this isn't possible. If the dictionary method is worth the time, my sugestion would be to parse a book or webpage that you think would contain a lot of them and pull all the words that contain `'`. From they create a unique list and then try break them up into contractions and not. That way you would at least not need to try and think of them all :)

Answer (score -1):

You can count the number of apostrophes that appear and add that to the number of words from `str_word_count`.

```
$string = "i'm not";
$count = str_word_count($string);
$count += substr_count($string, "'");

echo $count;
// $count == 3
```

Comment: What if the string contains `'` in other places? Like "I'm not 'bored'" - your method would yield 6 instead of 4.